# Writing files using django forms and multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

I am uploading a large number of files to server side using python multiprocessing technique and django forms.Here is the code

```
def pooltest(request):
    file_list=request.FILES.getlist('docfile')
    print 'cpu_count() = %d\n' % cpu_count()
    total_no_files = len(request.FILES.getlist('docfile'))
    chunk_size = total_no_files//cpu_count()
    print chunk_size
    t1 = time.time()
    p = Pool()
    p.map(upload_function, file_list,chunksize=chunk_size)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

But when i trying to upload large number of files following error occuring

```
expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
```

Please help to fix this?Is this pool configurations are correct?How do i change this so that i can upload large number of files with minimum time.

Here is the traceback

```
 expected string or Unicode object, NoneType found
Internal Server Error: /pooltest/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view matchingapp.views.pooltest didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
2017-02-28 12:52:17,218 [Thread-90   ] [ERROR]  Internal Server Error: /pooltest/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/akhil/.virtualenvs/resumematch/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 198, in _get_response
    "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view matchingapp.views.pooltest didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: i have modified the question@DanielRoseman

Comment: The stacktrace tells you exactly what the problem is. `pooltest` needs to return an `HttpResponse` but you aren't returning anything. Also, you should really queue this kind of stuff up and have a worker thread pull these off a queue. Don't upload files on the main HTTP thread.

Comment: Can you explain with an example pls?I am a begginer in multiprocessing.@themanatuf

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You should really use `celery` or `<queue of your choice>` instead of jumping into multiprocessing.
2. You should take into account that even with multiprocessing it could take a while for all the files to upload and the client will be waiting for some response from your view. I sense some timeouts in the Force.

And, as @themanatuf2 said, your view function should return a value, either a template or just `HttpResponse(status=200)`

Comment: This is not issue with the return.Error occuring in the line     p.map(upload_function, file_list,chunksize=chunk_size)

Comment: Your traceback says `ValueError: The view matchingapp.views.pooltest didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` that's what happens when you forget to return something the request dispatcher can work with, i.e an HttpResponse.